# restore compressed dump query in postgresql asks password

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I'm using ubuntu OS and I took backup using

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump dbname | gzip > filename.gz
```

in the file path as...

```
/home/administrator/Documents/DB_Backup# sudo -u postgres pg_dump dbname | gzip > filename.gz
```

Later, I tried to restore it back using these following below...

```
 1. gunzip -c filename.gz | psql glialmine
 2. cat filename.gz | gunzip | psql
 3. sudo -u postgres  psql pg_restore -d dbname  filename.gz
```

all these 3 restore option I used asks password, but I have only one login and I tried it and its not accepting it I also tried root password and linux login password too but its not working.

For first two it asks password like below

```
Password:
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

and for 3rd one it asks password and its error for my password like below

```
 Password for user pg_restore: 
 psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pg_restore"
```

Answer (score 3):

Find the postgresql installation folder containing [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). Edit the authentication chapter at the end of this file, adding

```
local   all         all                               trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

and restart. After that postgresql should not ask for the password to authenticate into any account if this is done from the *same* machine where the postgresql server is running.

Afterwards, change passwords to be sure you know them. Finally, remove the added lines from pg_hba.conf for more security. You can only bypass authentication because you already have root rights on that computer.